# error while installing angular/cli using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

When I tried to install angular cli using this command

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I got below mentioned error

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:  Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} 
(current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): 
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): 
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.9.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass): 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

any idea whats the issue?

my node version is 6.9.2 and npm version is 3.10.9

Comment: Update Node to version 8.9 or higher. That is a newer requirement. Then try this all again.

Comment: yes it was indeed about the node version, i uninstalled node and installed `v8.11.1`, and it worked. thanks @R.Richards

Answer (score 10):

Try using the below command from your project folder:

**`npm audit fix`**

If it still shows it has fixed only few of the vulnerabilities, then use the below command

**`npm audit fix --force`**

[Screen shot of the command that I used in my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thWE3.png)

Answer (score 5):

This warning told everything:

```
Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: **wanted** {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (**current**: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Only unix-based systems use `fsevents`, and You are using Windows!

Comment: I know that only unix-based systems are supported but I don't need the warning in all my builds. Do you know a way on windows to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all the things you have posted are **Warnings** and not errors.

It means the npm has skipped the dependencies.

This would be solved if you update the npm version to the latest, use this command:

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

// use **sudo** if you get permission error.

and try to install again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: after successfully updating npm, when i do try to install angular/cli again i get below mentioned warnings `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@6.0.7
updated 1 package in 44.551s`    and ng -v returns unrecognizable command

Comment: Whats your npm version now?

Comment: npm version now is 6.1.0

Comment: Try this ``npm i -f -g npm@latest``

Comment: still same warnings and couldn't recognize ng

Comment: while ng is not recognized as a command but this returns angular package version    `npm list -g @angular/cli`
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- @angular/cli@6.0.7  , whats missing here

Comment: try ``ng new demoProject``

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\ng -> C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.3.2
added 295 packages from 179 contributors in 120.715s
```